# Change product stock availability texts in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product-variations

I am trying to change the in stock text next to the quantity available in woocommerce. I am using the stock management in product variations.

I tried this code below:

```
// change stock text
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability', 'wcs_custom_get_availability', 1, 2);
function wcs_custom_get_availability( $availability, $variation ) {

    // Change In Stock Text
    if (  $variation->is_in_stock() ) {
        $availability['availability'] = __('Available!', 'woocommerce');
    }

    // Change Out of Stock Text
    if ( ! $variation->is_in_stock() ) {
        echo '-------------------------';
        echo __('Sold Out', 'woocommerce');
        $availability['availability'] = __('Sold Out', 'woocommerce');
    }

    return $availability;
}
```

The code above changes the text but it does not pull in the stock quantity number from the variation stock manager.

Comment: Hi LoicTheAztec, Can I get some help from you on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54606921/get-my-vatiations-to-show-on-the-customers-receipt-in-wordpress-and-woocommerce

Comment: I believe you helped me with it before but the posts were deleted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code will handle all cases including the stock amount display with your custom texts:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability_text', 'customizing_stock_availability_text', 1, 2);
function customizing_stock_availability_text( $availability, $product ) {
    if ( ! $product->is_in_stock() ) {
        $availability = __( 'Sold Out', 'woocommerce' );
    }
    elseif ( $product->managing_stock() && $product->is_on_backorder( 1 ) )
    {
        $availability = $product->backorders_require_notification() ? __( 'Available on backorder', 'woocommerce' ) : '';
    }
    elseif ( $product->managing_stock() )
    {
        $availability = __( 'Available!', 'woocommerce' );
        $stock_amount = $product->get_stock_quantity();

        switch ( get_option( 'woocommerce_stock_format' ) ) {
            case 'low_amount' :
                if ( $stock_amount <= get_option( 'woocommerce_notify_low_stock_amount' ) ) {
                    /* translators: %s: stock amount */
                    $availability = sprintf( __( 'Only %s Available!', 'woocommerce' ), wc_format_stock_quantity_for_display( $stock_amount, $product ) );
                }
            break;
            case '' :
                /* translators: %s: stock amount */
                $availability = sprintf( __( '%s Available!', 'woocommerce' ), wc_format_stock_quantity_for_display( $stock_amount, $product ) );
            break;
        }

        if ( $product->backorders_allowed() && $product->backorders_require_notification() ) {
            $availability .= ' ' . __( '(can be backordered)', 'woocommerce' );
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $availability = '';
    }

    return $availability;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Thanks for your help on the other question. Do you know how I can get the variation details to show on the customer's receipt?

Comment: For me, this does not work for "Out of stock". It does get to the line where the text is set to "Sold Out", but still, in the output the old "Out of stock" remains ... is there another place where this may be overwritten?
EDIT: Got it: On my site, it's a theme setting!